# How to prevent axes label and tick labels from being placed inside a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

Consider the following toy-code:

```
data = Table[{k, Sin[k], 0}, {k, 0, 1, 0.01}];

ListPointPlot3D[{data},
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, PointSize[Small]},
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {Floor[Min[data]], Floor[Min[data]], 0},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
]
```

which generates the following plot:

[image]

Note that the axis label "y" is inside the plot, i.e. to the right of the axis. How can I get the tick labels as well as the axis label to left of the axis?

Answer (score 9):

There's an `AxesEdge` option that might be worth exploring:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{data}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, PointSize[Small]}, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {Floor[Min[data]], Floor[Min[data]], 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I was not aware of that option. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. The documentation doesn't say anything that relates label placement to the use of this option. It's purported use is for selecting the location of the axes on the bounding box of the plot. Seems to work, though.